# Separate a function from a React component (improve modularity)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, modularity

I have created my first React application which takes data submitted by a user via a form and writes a message based on the data they've entered. I have used React with hooks to do this and would like to continue to use hooks.

Below is a cut down version of my component. I'd like to improve the modularity by extracting the getDate function and moving it into a separate js file. This will allow me to reuse it elsewhere. Could you advise how to do that based on my cut-down code below?

**NLG.js (all code in a single component)**

```
import React from 'react';
import {isYesterday, format} from 'date-fns';

const NLG = ({ watchAll }) => {

    const allAnswers = JSON.parse(watchAll);

        /*Convert date to language*/
        const getDate = (date) => { 
            if (isYesterday(date) === true) {
                return 'yesterday';
            }
            else {
                return 'on ' + format(date, 'EEEE');
            }
         };

  return (
      <p>
        {getDate(Date.parse(allAnswers['dateUpdateFailed']))}
      </p>
  );
};
export default NLG;
```

I have tried creating a new component called GetDate which contains my getDate function but in the structure of a functional component. It accepts a date prop and then I use the GetDate component in my NLG component. But I have been getting the following error: *"A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development."* I haven't included my failed attempt here as it made the question very lengthy.

I haven't needed to use state in the normal way so far in my application as it's built into React Hook Form which I'm using. But I suspect now is the time that I will need to learn how to use it?! Is anyone able to advise how to do the above? Many thanks :)

Katie

Comment: I don't really understand why not exporting it as a simple function from an external js file

Comment: Thanks GalAbra - good point. I tried that as well, but for some reason I'm getting an error "getDate is not defined". But I am starting to wonder if this is not a problem with having an external function but rather the way I am using it. In my real code I have a json file containing my getDate function as a value inside an array: "getDate(Date.parse(allAnswers['dateUpdateFailed']))" I am iterating through each item in the array using json.array.map((n) => eval(n)). Is there any reason why this works when the function is inside my main component but not if it is a simple function in a js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a great habit to separate your static functions from your components.
Just make sure you `export` and `import` them properly:

```
// getDate.js

import { isYesterday, format } from 'date-fns';

const getDate = (date) => {
  if (isYesterday(date) === true) {
    return 'yesterday';
  } else {
    return 'on ' + format(date, 'EEEE');
  }
}

export default getDate;
```

```
// NLG.jsx

import React from 'react';
import getDate from './getDate.js'; // Assuming they're both in the same directory

const NLG = ({ watchAll }) => {
  const allAnswers = JSON.parse(watchAll);
  return (
    <p>
      {getDate(Date.parse(allAnswers['dateUpdateFailed']))}
    </p>
  );
};

export default NLG;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply - this works perfectly when I call getDate() from within NLG.js. My problem now is that I have to pull getDate(Date.parse(allAnswers['dateUpdateFailed'])) as a string in my json file and then wrap eval() around it! It isn't working, but that's probably to do with how I'm writing the string - a question for another stackoverflow board! Thanks again - your answer has helped me eliminate the external js file as the cause of my problem! :-)